# Beans not being found after using profiles - Not sure why

Tags: java, spring

I originally had an xml file with the following sort of layout :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <bean id="FirstBean">...</bean>
   <bean id="SecondBean">...</bean>
   <bean id="ThirdBean">...</bean>
</beans>
```

Which worked well for us. But today we realized we only wanted some of the beans to be instantiated in certain environments (production and test) - and that we needed profiles in order for it to happen. We did this by nesting some  elements, and adding profiles, as follows :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

   <!-- Beans to run commonly amongst both profiles -->
   <beans>
       <bean id="FirstBean">...</bean>
   </beans>

   <!-- Beans to run in prod -->
   <beans profile="production">
       <bean id="SecondBean">...</bean>
   </beans>

   <!-- Beans to run in test -->
   <beans profile="test">
       <bean id="ThirdBean">...</bean>
   </beans>
</beans>
```

Then... In order to get the beans to load the correct beans - at the initial startup of the application - I perform the following (currently hardcoded for testing purposes) :

```
System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test");
```

I have also tried :

```
System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "production");
```

But now I keep getting "No such bean definition" on all three beans.

I hope I have provided enough information here. I really am stuck on this - have followed various online resources.

Comment: Too little information, only snippets and no overview. When/where are you setting those properties if you are trying to do that at startup in some bean you are too late.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to set an active Spring profile earlier in your application's startup. There are a few different ways to accomplish this.

**Quick Solution**

For testing purposes you can add a context-param to web.xml:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
   <display-name>Spring Web Application</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <!-- Set active Spring profile -->
   <context-param>
      <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
      <param-value>prod</param-value>
   </context-param>
</web-app>
```

**Programatic Solution**

You can set an active Spring profile programmatically at startup by passing a custom class that implements ApplicationContextInitializer to the DispatcherServlet. In your custom class add a method that overrides ApplicationContextInitializer's initialize method with code that sets an active Spring profile for the application context.

In web.xml pass your custom class that implements ApplicationContextInitializer to the DispatcherServlet as an init-param:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Spring Web Application</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <!-- Register custom class that implements ApplicationContextInitilizer to set active Spring profile on startup -->
         <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
         <param-value>org.eclipse.che.examples.MyApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Then define your custom class that implements ApplicationContextInitializer:

```java
package org.eclipse.che.examples;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

   @Override
   public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
      // set active Spring profile
      applicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("prod");
   }

}
```